# socketException: Connection reset in react native then app freezes

Tags: android, react-native, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-java-client

I have got an issue that makes the app freeze, As I reload the app it will work normally.
I tried debugging and it happens in these cases:

1. If I put the app in the background and use other apps.
2. Lock the phone, unlock it, and back to the app again.

**Error message** : `java.net.socketException: Connection reset`

**Actions** : try add network_security_config file to android manifest : `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

"react": "16.8.6",

"react-native": "^0.60.5",

"socket.io": "^2.2.0",

"socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",

How can I find the cause? and also how can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AkshayItaliya I refactor the whole component to a functional component and also my teammate reform socket connections.

Currently, I don't face freezes but actually, we didn't find the root cause.